# build configuration : Java backend (Spring + Maven) with JS project (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, spring, maven, build-process

we would like to improve build configuration/integration of Java + JavaScript projects.

- back-end : Java app, Spring framework, REST API + maven as build tool
- front-end : HTML + CSS + JavaScript, *(based on [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate) project template - it separates nicely all modules,services,directives,shared assets)* and it's using few JavaScript tools like npm, Bower, Karma + Grunt

Workspace configuration is pretty simple - each project in separate directory :

```
    /workspace
     /JavaBackend
     /JsFrontend
```

Problem is that developers are dealing with “Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" messages in browsers as they run AJAX queries from front-end (from file://..../JSApp/build/index.hml) and Java App server is on localhost:8080. We could switch browser security off or modify headers to allow cross origin requests but we think it's not good way how to achieve that.

We don't want to have JS resources inside of Java project in /src/main/webapps/ as in production environment apps will be deployed on different machines and each app has it's own build server.

Do you have experience with similar project configuration ? What would you recommend to us ?

*Meanwhile we will experiment with Tomcat 7 to check if it can e.g. serve external static resources (js stuff) out of context of java app*

Comment: I may prefer you start watching these tutorials that suits you requirements i guess=> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sc2atFv_h_I&list=PL4gCdGOq-cxJrbRMWjrIvGhYqQO1tvYyX

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes, I would let Tomcat include the front-end folder in the server.xml by means of a `<Context>` tag. The folder can be arbitrary and even in another repository (e.g. `/GitRepos/ApplicationGui/app`).

```
...
      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">    
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
        <Context docBase="/workspace/JsFrontend" path="/"/>
        <Context docBase="FlexibleOrders" path="/FlexibleOrders" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:FlexibleOrders"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

In production, I would recommend to make a Maven artefact out of the front-end. It can be then included via dependency in the backend like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-gui</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

See this blog for a complete configuration for production:

http://wiki.switajski.de/2016/01/24/how-to-create-maven-artifact-with-static-web-resources.html